# php's simplexml_load_file is not working

Tags: php, html, xml

So I've been working on this SIMPLE AS HELL php code and cannot figure out why it will not work. All I'm trying to do is parse some data inside an html file and display it all nice and neat. Here is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<posts>
<post>
<title>Overview</title>
<item>Why are great</item>
<item>Who WonderWidgets</item>
</post>
</posts>
```

and here is my php inside the html file...

```
<?php
$posts = simplexml_load_file('/Users/Sam/Desktop/untitled\ html/posts.xml')
echo $posts->post->title;
?>
```

I have tried everything I can think of...
The echo echoes only

```
->post->title; ?>
```

Why is it echoing '?>' ?
Is anyone else having this problem or am I just too stupid to figure out what is wrong here...
Other Information: 
It seems as though the variable $posts is empty when I tried this in the command line php.
I cannot occupy it and I have tried to do so with multiple xml files...HELP!

Edit:
I just tried this in my php shell and I get this error:

```
php > $posts = simplexml_load_file('posts.xml')
php > echo $posts
php > echo $posts->post->title;

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO in php shell code on line 2
```

My working directory is / and I have the posts.xml stored there.

Comment: You missed a semicolon at the end of your second line of PHP.

Comment: You don't need a backslash before the space. This may explain why `$posts` was empty. (I'm assuming the actual name of the file doesn't have a backslash there.)

Comment: I've Already done so... @JonathonReinhart

Comment: does the $posts contain anything? try a var_dump($posts).

Comment: I would recommend changing the title to the problem you are having.

Comment: I took the backslash out and i get the same result every time...@DavidKnipe

Comment: Could you look at your source to see if the PHP is even interpreted? I suspect you gave it an `.html` extention & it isn't even parsed as PHP.

Comment: It does not contain anything...I cannot get it to contain anything with other xml files either. What is wrong with this thing??? @kostaskostarelo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried putting your XML in `test.xml` and tried your example. It worked fine. I got the output as overview.

Check your path to the file. Check the slashes in the path.

```
$posts = simplexml_load_file('test.xml');
echo $posts->post->title;
```

Comment: I just tried in my shell...and got this result...I change the location of my xml twice and got the same error because the variable $posts didn't have anything in it...
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in php shell code on line 2

Comment: instead of echo try return print_r($posts);

Comment: Hey sorry this kind of late, but I just wanted to clarify that I went full retard and was attempting to run PHP on my local machine. Now I know a lot more about it though so I promise I'm not stupid anymore...Thanks again though!